# Getting Typescript error when I run an npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I run `tsc && npm run browserify && npm run minify` I get this error:

```
lib/helper.ts:71:38 - error TS4078: Parameter 'inputData' of exported function has or is using private name 'Buffer'.

71   inputData: NodeJS.ReadableStream | Buffer | string
```

From what I can see, I should be exporting Buffer in some way but I'm not sure what that means or how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nodejs typings. Simply run `npm install @types/node`.

EDIT: If that's not the problem, then you should go to your `lib/helper.ts` and export the private `Buffer`, as `inputData` is exported and using Buffer, but Buffer is not exported.

Info extracted [from here](https://github.com/angular/tsickle/issues/301).

Comment: That was it. Thanks!